# MoviePy : Slow down the rendering of videos

Tags: performance, moviepy, slowdown

I actually try to display a video with Python and MoviePy, but when the script run the video, it is playing with my_clip.preview() but seem like at 1FPS. 
When I check inside my code the FPS of my video, they said me 30/sec. For more details, the script running on a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B+ (2GB RAM / 1.5GHZ).

I have check the processor and it's good, also when I try to run the video from VLC or OMXPlayer everything is okay. The video hasn't any lag or bad FPS. So, I don't know why MoviePy, which normally use the default player(VLC here), slow down my video render if with VLC player it doesn't happen.

I can provide some code if needed, but it's a classic moviePy program.

I have tried my code on my Mac OS and moviePy doesn't slow down the video. On my code, with my_clip.fps, the FPS are the same than when I execute the code on my Mac. 
Probably the mistake come from to Raspberry ?

I would know what happen and how to solve, if possible, this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The raspberry pi probably doesn't have enough speed to render 30fps every second so it only manages to make 1 frame per seconds and that is what you are seeing.